# Detect if click was inside react component or not in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have roughly the following:

```
componentDidMount() {                                                                                                                                                                                           
  document.querySelector('body')!.addEventListener('click', this.click);
} 

click = (e: Event) => {                                                                                                                                                                                         
  if (this.state.toggled) {
    if (!ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.someRef).contains(e.target)) {
      this.setState({ toggled: false });
    }
  }
};

render() {
  return (<CustomElement
    ref={(e) => { this.someRef = e; }}                                                                                                                                                                   
  />)
}
```

This code correctly detects whether the user clicks inside or outside the CustomElement, so far so good.

However, `tsc` isn't happy with this at all:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Property 'attributes' is missing in type 'EventTarget'.
```

Looking at `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts` this makes sense, since `e.target` is an `EventTarget` which appears to only define the functions for adding and removing event handlers. However [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) says e.target is "A reference to the object that dispatched the event." which sounds closer to what I want.

So how do I retain the currently working functionality, while also making tsc happy (as opposed to just silencing the error)?

Answer (score 85):

I found a similar discussion in the [typescript issue queue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15394) which says in this case a type assertion is [probably unavoidable](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15394#issuecomment-297495746):

> Basically EventTarget is the most general type, of which Element is a subtype, and HTMLElement is a subtype of that. If you get back a thing from the DOM, we generally have no idea which it is, and you should add a type assertion to "add in" the specific external knowledge that you have about the structure of your particular DOM layout.
>
> It's possible, for example, that the .target of an event is not an Element (you can add event listeners to XMLHttpRequest, for example, and XMLHttpRequest does not have a getBoundingClientRect method).

So because target may or may not be a `Node` like I want, TS can't infer the truth, and I need to assert.

`contains(e.target as Node)` appears to be the right solution.

Answer (score 15):

How about defining your click handler like this:

```
private click = (e: Event) =>
{
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLElement && !ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.someRef).contains(e.target))
    {
        if (this.state.toggled)
        {
            this.setState({ toggled: false });
        }
    }
}
```

Sample [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNOQQO).

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what the benefit is here, it looks to me like this silences the error, such that tsc will now assume that the inner code never run since it will consider the instanceof check to always fail?

Comment: Try it. I have tested the proposed code and it actually always succeed as HtmlElement is the base for other elements. And it will not really silence the error (unlike casting to any) - instead it will do a valid check and continue if it is true.

Comment: I have attached example for you to check.

Answer (score 8):

this is what works for me the point is you should also provide a type for your ref :

```js
 const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const handleClickOutside = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (
      wrapperRef?.current?.contains(event.target as Node) &&
      isFocusLockDisabled
    ) {
      return foo(false);
    }
  };
```